# Change atrribute of the <div></div> Comment Form in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Im using the COMMMENT FORM in WORDPRESS but I wanna customize the form.The form is wraped by default:

```
<div id="respond" class="comment-respond">
...
</div>
```

Now I want to add some class attributes to  tag.So can I use filter hook to make that or anyone have good idea for this problem.Thanks

Comment: how is your code? put it here for us

Answer (score 0):

This is code of file comments.php:

```
<div class="wilpost-component__module mb-30">
<?php if (have_comments() == false) { ?>
    <h3 class="postComponent-title">No comment</h3>
<?php } else { ?>
    <h3 class="postComponent-title"><?php echo esc_html("(" . get_comments_number() . ")comment"); ?></h3>
    <div class="wilpost-comment__module">
        <ol class="commentlist">
            <?php
            wp_list_comments(array('callback' => 'fractal_comment', "style" => "ol"));
            ?>
        </ol>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
</div>
<?php comment_form();?>
```

And this is code I wanna customize my comment form like this:

```
 <div class="wilform__module wilform__feedback">
    <form name="wil-feedback" id="wil-feedback" action="#">
        <div class="item-group">
            <label for="name">name</label>
            <input type="text" id="name"/>
            <div class="form-icon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></div>
        </div>
        <div class="item-group">
            <label for="email">email</label>
            <input type="email" id="email"/>
            <div class="form-icon"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></div>
        </div>
        <div class="item-group">
            <label for="textarea">textarea</label>
            <textarea></textarea>
        </div>
        <button class="wil-btn wil-btn--primary wil-btn--md wil-btn--round " type="submit">Subscrible<i class="la la-paper-plane"></i>
        </button>
    </form>
</div>
```